# Using data-* attribute with Thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

Can I set data-* attribute with Thymeleaf?

As I understood from Thymeleaf documentation I tried:

```
<div th:data-el_id="${element.getId()}"> <!-- doesn't work -->

<div data-th-el_id="${element.getId()}"> <!-- doesn't work -->
```

Comment: This was a bug, [fixed for Thymeleaf 3.0](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/489). This question is relevant only for pre 3.0 version. For newer ones `th:data-el_id` will work.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Yes, `th:attr` to the rescue [Thymeleaf documentation - Setting attribute values](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes).

For your scenario, this should do the job:

```
<div th:attr="data-el_id=${element.getId()}">
```

XML rules do not allow you to set an attribute twice in a tag, so you can't have more than one `th:attr` in the same element.

Note: If you want more that one attribute, separate the different attributes by comma:

```
<div th:attr="data-id=${element.getId()},data-name=${element.getN‌​ame()}">
```

Comment: Just a note for future readers, you can't have more than one th:attr in the same element so just use one and separate the different attributes by comma: `th:attr="data-id=${element.getId()},data-name=${element.getName()}"`

Comment: If you need to include a variable as part of a string you need to do this: `th:attr="data-id='some-text'+${element.getId()}+'some-other-text',data-name=${element.getName()}"`

Comment: @AntonioOtero 's comment should be part of the answer.

Comment: I wish attribute processing would not be restricted to certain attributes but rather be generally handled. Has anyone heard that it will be feature? (Well blame on me, I did not check the version 3 yet ;-)

Answer (score 22):

With Thymeleaf 3.0 there is the [Default Attribute Processor](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-the-value-of-any-attribute-default-attribute-processor) which can be used for any kind of custom attributes, e.g. `th:data-el_id=""` becomes `data-el_id=""`, `th:ng-app=""` becomes `ng-app=""` and so on. There is no need for the beloved data attribute dialect anymore.

This solution I prefer, **if I want to use json** as the value, instead of:

```html
<div th:attr="data-foobar='{&quot;foo&quot:'+${bar}+'}'">
```

You can use (in combination with [literal substitution](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions)):

```html
<div th:data-foobar='|{"foo":${bar}}|'>
```

**Update:** If you don't like the `th` namespace, you can also use [HTML5 friendly attribute and element names](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#support-for-html5-friendly-attribute-and-element-names) like `data-th-data-foobar=""`.

*If someone is interested, related template engine tests can be found here: [Tests for Default Attribute Processor](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-tests/tree/3.0-spring51/src/test/resources/templateengine/attrprocessors/default)*

Answer (score 14):

Or you can use this Thymeleaf dialect https://github.com/mxab/thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute and you'll be able do

```
<div data:el_id="${element.getId()}">
```